# Does Liferay have a database that ponts to physical content, such as pdf, by name?

Tags: database, liferay, splunk

I will make this as explicit as I can in hopes that someone might understand and point me in the right direction. I am not, repeat **NOT**, a Liferay developer. Instead I have been assigned the task of using Splunk to consume Liferay web access logs and create web site activity dashboards from these logs. The Liferay developers don’t seem to quite comprehend what I need to do and they work in a different part of the country so I can’t just sit down with them. So here is a sample web site structure and content.

```
FordCarMaintenance.html
    Escort
        EscortEngineRemoval.pdf
        EscortEnginetuneUp.pdf
        EscortTransmissionDraining.pdf
        ReplaceEscortRadiator.flv
        EscortContactList.html
    Ranger
        RangerAlignmentCheckList.pdf
        RoadHazardandTireWear.pdf
        EngineMountReplacement.pdf
        RangerTransmissionFramusReplacement.pdf
```

The Liferay logs will have reference to Escort and Ranger but will not have a direct reference to the pdf, flv and html files. My job, however, is to tell my end user how many times those individual pdf, flv and html files have been viewed.
The key field in the Liferay log will look something like this:

```
/group/escort/1266711/maintenance/engine
/group/escort/1266719/maintenance/engine 
/group/escort/1266413/maintenance/transmission  
/group/escort/1266700/maintenance/radiator  
/group/escort/1266695/maintenance/contacts  
/group/ranger/6569235/maintenance/alignment  
/group/ranger/6569239/maintenance/hazard  
/group/ranger/6569351/maintenance/engine  
/group/ranger/6569772/maintenance/transmission
```

Note that under the last part of the "friendly URL" such as engine there may be multiple engine related pages (1266711, 1266719). My understanding is that the number between the slashes points to a field in a database table(s) that can actually identify the physical file by name and extension that the users are accessing under the type escort/maintenance/engine. I believe that Liferay has a database table named journalArticle that has this information. So now my questions:

Does the journalArticle table actually have this information such that a query to the table looking for:

articleID = 1266711

will return EscortEngineRemoval.pdf?

Or is there another table or set of tables that combined have this data? Am I even close?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `DLFileEntry` table, it has `fileEntryId` column that is the number you are referring too and another column `title` that holds the name of the file. The structure of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `DLFileEntry` (
  `uuid_` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fileEntryId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `groupId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `companyId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifiedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `classNameId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classPK` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `repositoryId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `folderId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `treePath` longtext,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mimeType` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext,
  `extraSettings` longtext,
  `fileEntryTypeId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size_` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `readCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smallImageId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `largeImageId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom1ImageId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom2ImageId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manualCheckInRequired` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fileEntryId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_5391712` (`groupId`,`folderId`,`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_ED5CA615` (`groupId`,`folderId`,`title`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_BC2E7E6A` (`uuid_`,`groupId`),
  KEY `IX_4CB1B2B4` (`companyId`),
  KEY `IX_772ECDE7` (`fileEntryTypeId`),
  KEY `IX_8F6C75D0` (`folderId`,`name`),
  KEY `IX_F4AF5636` (`groupId`),
  KEY `IX_93CF8193` (`groupId`,`folderId`),
  KEY `IX_29D0AF28` (`groupId`,`folderId`,`fileEntryTypeId`),
  KEY `IX_43261870` (`groupId`,`userId`),
  KEY `IX_D20C434D` (`groupId`,`userId`,`folderId`),
  KEY `IX_D9492CF6` (`mimeType`),
  KEY `IX_64F0FE40` (`uuid_`),
  KEY `IX_31079DE8` (`uuid_`,`companyId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll pass this to my Liferay developers to see what they say. I have the feeling they don't know the Liferay internals but just how to make API calls. If they can provide me with what I need form this table I'll be back to accept this answer.

Comment: If they refuse to look at the database and rather opt for the API: Thank them for their future proof mind. The database might change at any time, and if they know the db internals, they might be tempted to write to the database as well - this typically leads to disaster sooner or later. If you're lucky: Sooner. There is an API for DLFileEntry as well. SOAP, JSONWS, Java: All available to you